# How to apply conjugate symbol in LyX for complex numbers?

Tags: lyx

I've been trying to figure out how to apply the conjugate symbol on top of a complex number "z" in LyX, and I couldn't figure it out. Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want? Can you link to an example picture? The following page suggests an overbar or an asterisk is used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Notation

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note that you need to use an at-sign before the username to make sure the user is notified, i.e. @scottkosty, not just scottkosty. (Only works in comments, with other commenters, and no more than one user per comment. Tab-completion is available.)

Comment: @scottkosty I want to use the bar conjugate symbol on top of a variable called "z", but the tutorial or other resources didn't really answer my question with how to put that conjugate symbol on top of my variable.

Comment: @serendipity456 `\bar{z}` is the way. How to do it with LyX is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @serendipity456 thanks for the explanation. Be sure to see the answer by  Torbjørn T. and to accept it if it solves your question. I think he covered all of the possible approaches in LyX.

Answer (score 5):

There are at least three ways of getting `\bar`, or alternatively, `\overline` in LyX:

1. Type it directly: In math mode, type `\bar` (or `\overline`) followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>. Then type the `z` or whatever, and hit the space bar or use the right arrow key to move out of the inset.
2. Use the keyboard shortcut:

   - `\bar`: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>
   - `\overline`: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

   (I.e. hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>M</kbd>, release both and hit <kbd>-</kbd>.)
3. Use the button on the math toolbar, specifically the one showing a dotted box with a hat on it. You get a panel of options. `\bar` is number three from the left on the top row, `\overline` is the one that's highlighted.

   [image]